# The correct use of me or I

Tags: grammar

Which is correct, me and Robyn are going to the bar, or Robyn and I are going to the bar?

Comment: As has been repeated *many* times, for simple cases like this simply drop the "and Robin" (changing "are" to "is" or "am" if needed) and see how it sounds.

Answer (score 2):

Would you say "I am going to the bar" or "Me am going to the bar"?
Well, that's what you'd say even if you were going with Robyn.

Also, usually (?) it's considered polite to put yourself last, so...